# Controller not getting mapped

Tags: spring-boot

My controller is not getting mapped in the console.

My main class Application

```
package com.ruchi.web.sbfirst;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SbFirstApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SbFirstApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

LoginController

```
package com.ruchi.web.sbfirst.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginMessage() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not getting mapped in console? are you not able to access this path?

Comment: Please post your pom.xml or build.gradle file.

Comment: @RequestMapping("/login") add method for this like get /put post

Comment: @EugenCovaci

My console:
https://pastecode.xyz/view/40f1e1d6

Comment: My pom file: https://pastecode.xyz/view/0802a882

Comment: @silentsudo I cannot see "/login"  in my console after adding Controller class

Answer (score 0):

Add **@RestController** annotation before the  LoginController class

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginMessage() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

Reason you are using spring boot and also if you want to use @Controller annotation enable WebMVC.

Comment: add @EnableWebMVC annotation before your main class

Answer (score 0):

click on the your project and go to the gradle or maven (which ever you have used) and refresh it then built your project and now re-run it this time it will not disappoint your :)